# Riemann-Hilbert problem via quiver description

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules, quiver-varieties

The moduli space of Fuchsian systems over $\mathbb{P}^1$ with prescribed adjoint orbits conditions at poles a.k.a. additive Deligne-Simpson problem can be presented under purely quiver description.The quiver is give by $\{A_i\in \mathcal{O}^i_{\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})}, i=1,2,…,m|\sum A_i=0\}/\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Meanwhile, the solution of multiplicative Deligne-Simpson problem is subset of character varieties $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1(\mathbb{P^1}-\{p_1,…,p_m\}),\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}))/\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$

which can be described by multiplicative quiver variety directly, i.e. the space $\{M_i\in \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})}^i,i=1,…,m|M_1M_2…M_m=1\}/\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.

To get a map from additive one to multiplicative one via quiver ,my naive hope is to translate the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence into quiver language. More precisely, Let’s assume $A_i$ are nonresonant, consider the monodromy of connection $d+\sum \frac{A_i}{z-i}dz$, then $e^{2i\pi A_i}$ will conjugate to the monodromy matrix around point $z=i$, so we can define a map from additive Deligne-Simpson problem to the multiplicative one by taking exponential $(A_1,…,A_m)\to (e^{2i\pi A_1},…,e^{2i\pi A_m})$ and then conjugate each $e^{2i\pi A_j}$ to monodromy matrix around $z=i$.

I don’t know if these conjugacy matrices can be expressed by $A_i$, But at least by looking at monodromy we have a well-defined map from additive one to multiplicative one. If $A_i$ are not nonresonant, I’m even not sure taking monodromy will send conjugacy class of $A_i$ to conjugacy class of $M_i$, any counterexample will also help.

And I wonder in general, can we set up an isomorphism of these two quiver varieties by Riemann-Hilbert correspondence? Or do we have an isomorphism in purely quiver description?

Comment: I suppose you are aware that $\sum A_i=0$ doesn't imply $\prod \exp(A_i)=I$?

Comment: @abx Oh, thanks for point it out, I’ve edit this question to make it more sensible.

Comment: Well, I still don't understand what is the map from the additive set-up to the multiplicatve one.

Comment: @abx Sorry, I should be more precise. It's just monodromy, but in the case A_i are nonresonant, exp(A_i) are conjugate to monodromy matrix, and monodromy matrices automatically satisfy the product condition. My hope is to express the conjugacy matrix between exp(A_i) and monodromy matrix using the quiver data. And In general I’m not sure if monodromy map is still a well defined map or not.

Comment: @TaiatLyu: The map sending a connection with regular singularities to its monodromy is not bijective, even in the nonresonant setting; for example, the monodromy of $d+a\cdot dz/z$ is the same as that of $d+(a+1)dz/z$.

Comment: @DanielLitt Thanks for your comment! But these two matrices $a$ and $a+1$ do not fall in the same conjugacy class right? All I want is just a map from additive one to multiplicative one, so I always fix the conjugacy class of $A_i$.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, and I would like to. Here is a long comment on where I have seen this. Let $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$, $(\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n)$ and $(\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_n)$ be three $n$-tuples of real numbers. Klyachko https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=1799623 showed that the following are equivalent: (1) There are Hermitian matrices $(A,B,C)$ with spectra $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ such that $A+B+C=0$ (2) There are matrices $(P,Q,R)$ with singular values $\exp(\alpha)$, $\exp(\beta)$, $\exp(\gamma)$ such that $PQR = \text{Id}$. (continued)

Comment: Alexeev, Meinrecken and Woodward https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=1871286 strengthened Klyachko's result by showing that the moduli space of such $(A,B,C)$, modulo $U(n)$ action, is diffeomorphic to the moduli space of such $(P,Q,R)$ modulo $U(n)^3$ action.

Comment: I showed https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=2132865 that both of these are equivalent to (3) there are positive definite Hermitian $X$, $Y$, $Z$ such that $X^{-1} Y$, $Y^{-1} Z$ and $Z^{-1} X$ has spectrum $\exp(2 \alpha)$, $\exp(2 \beta)$, $\exp(2 \gamma)$. The relation between (2) and (3) is elementary, but the connection to (1) is highly mysterious. In particular, notice that (1) is clearly preserved under replacing $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ by $(c \alpha, c \beta, c \gamma)$ for any scalar $c$, and that is highly nonobvious for the others.

Comment: I was discussing this with David Ben-Zvi a number of years ago, and he said that the relationship between (1) and (2) was obvious, and was the monodromy map that you propose.

Comment: This turns out to not be quite right, but here is the right version: Take three points in $\mathbb{RP}^1$ and take the connection which has simple poles with residues $\tfrac{1}{2 \pi i} A$, $\tfrac{1}{2 \pi i} B$, $\tfrac{1}{2 \pi i} C$ at this points. Then $P$, $Q$, $R$ are the parallel transport between points on $\mathbb{RP}^1$ between the poles, along paths in the upper half plane, and $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are the parallel transports from $i$ to $-i$ along paths crossing $\mathbb{RP}^1$ in the three possible places.

Comment: This excited me, because I really wanted to understand the asymptopic behavior, in $(X, Y, Z)$ coordinates, of this construction for $(c \alpha, c \beta, c \gamma)$ as $c \to \infty$. So I spent a bunch of time reading up on the Deligne-Simpson problem and on asymptotics of ODEs. But I was never able to find a source clear enough to let me prove anything (including that I couldn't reprove the Alexeev, Meinrecken, Woodward result).

Comment: So, this is a long comment to say "I don't know", but I really hope that someone will give a better answer!

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Really really thanks for your excellent comments, I just naively hope these two spaces should be same and then I only need to deal with topology rather than meromophic connections, and I never realize it is such a deep question, I really learn a lot from your comments, many thanks again.

Comment: Your question is simpler, because it doesn't have all of the real structure (Hermitian matrices, singular values, etc..) that mine does. One might hope that would make it easier ... I hope someone will leave a good answer.

Comment: @TaiatLyu: Oh, I understand now, you're fixing conjugacy classes--thank you. FWIW it might help to make this clearer in the question, i.e. explicitly define the spaces you are considering and the map between them. One maybe not-entirely-obvious observation is that the map you are considering genuinely depends on the points $p_i$. I do not believe it is surjective in general.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the map you are considering is surjective in general. Let us consider the case where where you have $m=4$ points and all the $A_i$ lie in the conjugacy class of
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$ and so all the $M_i$ live in the conjugacy class of $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
There is a canonical local system on $\mathbb{P}^1-\{x_1, \cdots, x_4\}$, called the *uniformizing* local system, with these local monodromies; its (global) monodromy depends on the $x_i$. One can construct it via non-abelian Hodge theory as follows: it is a complex variation of Hodge structure, with corresponding graded Higgs bundle $\mathscr{O}(1)\oplus \mathscr{O}(-1)$, where the Higgs field $$\mathscr{O}(1)\to \mathscr{O}(-1)\otimes \Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^1}(x_1+\cdots+x_4)=\mathscr{O}(1)$$ is a non-zero isomorphism.

But this implies the flat bundle $(\mathscr{E}, \nabla)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ with regular singularities at the $x_i$ and residues $A_i$ in our nilpotent conjugacy class has underlying vector bundle $\mathscr{E}=\mathscr{O}(1)\oplus \mathscr{O}(-1)$, i.e. the corresponding ODE is not "Fuchsian" (if I understand correctly, these are the ODEs you are considering -- please correct me if I'm wrong). Since this bundle is unique by the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence, there is no Fuchsian ODE with the required monodromy, so the monodromy of the uniformizing local system is not in the image of your map.

EDIT: The OP asks for a non-resonant example, i.e. one where the $A_i$ have distinct eigenvalues which do not differ by integers. I think one can make one as follows. Let $A_1, A_2, A_3$ lie in the conjugacy class of
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1/4 & 0 \\ 0 & 3/4 \end{pmatrix}$$ and let $A_4$ lie in the conjugacy class of $$\begin{pmatrix} -3/4 & 0 \\ 0 & -9/4 \end{pmatrix}$$
We first construct a stable graded parabolic Higgs bundle with weights $(1/4, 3/4)$ at each of $x_1, \cdots, x_4$. Namely, let $$\mathscr{E}=\mathscr{O}(-1)\oplus \mathscr{O}(-3),$$ with Higgs field $$\theta:\mathscr{O}(-1)\to \mathscr{O}(-3)\otimes \Omega^1(x_1+\cdots+x_4)=\mathscr{O}(-1)$$ non-zero, and parabolic weights $(1/4, 3/4, 1/4, 3/4)$ on $\mathscr{O}(-1)$ at $x_1, \cdots, x_4$, and weights $(3/4, 1/4, 3/4, 1/4)$ on $\mathscr{O}(-3)$ at $x_1,\cdots, x_4$. This bundle is parabolically stable of (parabolic) slope zero, since $\mathscr{O}(1)_\star$ has parabolic degree $1$ and $\mathscr{O}(-3)_\star$ has parabolic degree $-1$. The corresponding ODE is not Fuchsian for the same reason as in the previous example; its residues all lie in the conjugacy class of $$\begin{pmatrix} 1/4 & 0 \\ 0 & 3/4 \end{pmatrix}.$$
The OP might reasonably argue that this is unfair, since the sum of the traces of the $A_i$ is non-zero; but twisting up by $\mathscr{O}(2x_4)$ makes the residue at $x_4$ lie in the conjugacy class of $$\begin{pmatrix} -3/4 & 0 \\ 0 & -9/4 \end{pmatrix}$$ and doesn't change the fact that the ODE is still not Fuchsian.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So the exponential map method may only works for nonresonant cases, as you give a beautiful counterexample in nilpotent case. But I still hope there is a bijection between these two spaces given by looking at monodromy, or some other method.

Comment: @TaiatLyu: I've added a non-resonant example...

Comment: Many thanks! So maybe it’s impossible to build up an isomorphism via looking at monodromy, the relation between these two varieties are really much more mysterious than I thought.